# How can I get the name of a function?

Tags: javascript, function, inheritance

How can I get the name of a function? For example, I have a function:

```
function Bot(name, speed, x, y) {
    this.name = name;
    this.speed = speed;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}
```

and I have a method which returns info about Bot:

```
Bot.prototype.showPosition = function () {
    return `I am ${Bot.name} ${this.name}. I am located at ${this.x}:${this.y}`; //I am Bot 'Betty'. I am located at -2:5.
}
```

So then i have a function which inherits the Bot function:

```
function Racebot(name, speed, x, y) {
    Bot.call(this, name, speed, x, y);
}

Racebot.prototype = Object.create(Bot.prototype);
Racebot.prototype.constructor = Racebot;
let Zoom = new Racebot('Lightning', 2, 0, 1);
console.log(Zoom.showPosition());
```

Zoom.showPosition should return:

```
I am Racebot 'Lightning'. I am located at 0:1.
```

But it returns `I am Bot` not `I am Racebot`.

How can I do that?

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using ES6 classes ?

Comment: replace ${Bot.name} with ${this.name} in showPosition method

Comment: Your function explicitly uses the value `Bot.name`, which can never be anything other than "Bot".  You can use `this.constructor.name` instead.

Answer (score 3):

When you replace `this.constructor.name` with `Bot.name` in your showPosition() function it should work.

This is because `Bot.name` will always return the name of your Bot() function, whereas `this.constructor.name` looks up the name of the function set as `constructor` property on the prototype of your Racebot instance (which is "Racebot" due to `Racebot.prototype.constructor = Racebot)`